# How do I only allow authenticated user (using cognito) access to their own S3 bucket/key specifically?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Our basic app flow is as follows:

React app: user signs in ---> gets authenticated using cognito --> then is redirected to a portal where they can upload files to s3

The way "folders" are structured in s3 is as follows:
email for each user has a folder/key in the s3 bucket (lets call this bucket "testbucket").

So if my email is john@google.com then  it will look like this: Bucket - testbucket, key - john@google.com

And john can only upload to that folder.

Now my question is, right now I am checking if the "key" exists, if not deny request to s3. However with the layer of KMS added, I want to know, do I pass the kms "master key" when making the request in node? If so do I just save the key in env variable for example and pass it in when making the call?

In addition, can I add something in the policy that ties the access to cognito or the user email that is authenticated? if so could I get an example on how to do this? (how to implement a sample policy)

edit 1: policy user

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "cognito/users/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/cognito/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/cognito/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

edit 2: revised policy

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "cognito/users/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/cognito/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/cognito/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I am making the api call like so:

```js
var authenticate = (val) => {
  var userData = {
    Username: val.user, // your username here
    Pool: userPool
  };
  var authenticationData = {
    Username: val.user, // your username here
    Password: val.pass, // your password here
  };
  var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

  var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);

  cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function(result) {
      var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
      var idtoken = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();

      var params = {
        IdentityPoolId: 'ca-central-1:****',
        Logins: {
          'cognito-idp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/****': result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
        }
      }
      var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();
      cognitoidentity.getId(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
          var id = data.IdentityId;
          console.log(id);
          var params = {
            Bucket: 'mybucket',
            Key: `cognito/users/${id}/image.jpg`
          };
          s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
            else console.log(data);
          });
        }
      });



    },
    onFailure: function(err) {
      console.log("---------")
      console.log(`this is ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
    }
  });



}
```

Latest Edit:

```js
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: function(result) {
          var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
          var idtoken = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
          var params = {
            IdentityPoolId: 'ca-central-1:***',
            Logins: {
              'cognito-idp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/***': result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
            }
          }
          var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();
          cognitoidentity.getId(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else {
              // console.log(data);
              var id = data.IdentityId;
              console.log(id);

              var params = {
                IdentityId: `${id}`,
                Logins: {
                  'cognito-idp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/***': result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
                }
              };
              cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else {
                  // console.log(data);           // successful response
                  var creds = new AWS.Credentials({
                    accessKeyId: `${data.Credentials.AccessKeyId}`,
                    secretAccessKey: `${data.Credentials.secretAccessKey}`,
                    sessionToken: `${data.Credentials.SessionToken}`
                  })
                  var s3 = new AWS.S3(creds);
                  console.log(creds);
                  var params = {};
                  s3.listBuckets(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                    else console.log(data);
                  });

                }
              });



            }
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to restrict access would be by creating a dynamic policy. You can do this by creating a policy based on sub variable of cognito identity pool. Note that this sub isn't the same as the one you see in the cognito user pool. It is the identity Id you can get by calling the [GetId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html) api. 
You can create a policy using this sub so that the user only has access to keys with prefix containing this sub. So basically you are restricting access by folder. You can read more about this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189322/discussion-between-user2763557-and-ninad-gaikwad).

Comment: quick question. When I set s3 credentials. Do i need to set them on every api call?

Comment: Cognito temporary credentials expire after every 1 hour. After that you have to use your refresh token to get new identity Id and generate new credentials. You can either do this manually or use something like aws amplify which will do it for you automatically.